# What is the correct Python Package Index file structure?

Tags: python, package, pypi

I've created a Python library that I've uploaded to PyPI. Below is my current file structure, where `mylib.py` is where I put my library file. When I import to Python I have to type `from mylib import mylib` for it to work. I want to just type `import mylib` instead. I assume it's to do where I've put the file?

```
packageFolder
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── mylib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mylib.py
└── setup.py
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me. -- https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: It works fine yes, but I have to put "from mylib import mylib" for it to work, I just want to put "import mylib" and use the library like you would just put "import numpy" and use it. You dont have to go "from numpy import numpy".

Comment: I see. Then you could move the code from `mylib/mylib.py` into `mylib/__init__.py` (or make something like `from mylib import *` in `mylib/__init__.py`). This way you could do either `import mylib; mylib.myfunction()` or `from mylib import myfunction; myfunction()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move whatever you've defined in `mylib.py` that you plan to import (functions, variables, etc) into your `__init__.py` file.

For example, if you currently have to do:

```py
from mylib import mylib
mylib.foo()
```

Move `foo` into `__init__.py` and you can do:

```py
import mylib
mylib.foo()
```

instead.